# Bootstrap 3.0 Navigation Dropdown Not Working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Navigation Dropdown set in a Navbar that looks the way it should but is not dropping the menu down when clicked.

The code I have is:

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a id="dLabel" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
      Liane Stevenson
      <b class="caret"></b>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>
         <a href="#">Messages</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The declarations I have are:

```
<!--Styes & Bootstrap-->
<link href="Content/Styles/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Styles/additional.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Jquery & Boostrap JS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you added bootstrap.css ?

Comment: The code seems fine (http://www.bootply.com/QJ2mgAg9Np), as @SnehalShah told you, check that your bootstrap js and css are being accesed fine.

Comment: theme.min.css is the Bootstrap - I got it from a Bootstrap theme builder

Comment: The JS and CSS file work perfectly fine for the tabs - I did notice though that it stopped working when I changed the row class from row to row fluid?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the code. I am using a cdn for both the css and js and it works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/k3xff116/

Comment: Just done a small test and found that it is the row-fluid that's causing the problem - is there any way around that?

Comment: Can you show the entire navbar html? Its difficult to understand where you are replacing the row with row fluid.

Comment: Here's the JS Fiddle - but for some reason that works - https://jsfiddle.net/mxk1r0ab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the height fix I had used was what was stopping the drop down from displaying the way it should.

```
.row-fluid{
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

If I take this out, the drop down works